# How do I set up reset-password functionality using node.js?

Tags: node.js

Please I need help writing my forgot-password logic. I have tested what I have using Postman but its not working. I am using nodemailer as the mailserver engine .The entire project is been wired using Angular 4/5 (suggested solutions should please consider this factor). Please help check through and give recommendations/corrections. Thanks.

Here is the code so far--

//forgot password

```
const transport  = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
app.get('/forgotPassword', function(req, res){

    });
app.post('/forgotPassword', function(req, res, next){
    async.waterfall([
        function(done) {
            crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
                const token = buf.toString('hex');
                done(err, token);
            });
        },
        function(token, done) {
            user.findOne({email: req.body.email }, function(err, user, req) {
                if (!user){
                    console.log ('No account with that email address exists.');

                }
                user.resetPasswordToken = token;
                user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; //1 hour

            });
        },
        function(token, user, done){
            const smtpTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'Gmail',
                auth: {
                    user: 'preciousegunjobi@gmail.com',
                    pass: 'Presidoe2011!'
                }
            });

            const mailOptions = {
                from: 'preciousegunjobi1@gmail.com', //sender
                to: req.body.email, 
                subject: 'Password Reset Notification',
                html: '<h3>You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password on your account. ' + '\n' + ' Please click on the following link, or paste into your browser to complete the password reset process. </h3>' +' \n '+ 'http://' + req.headers.host + '/reset/' + token + '\n\n' +
                       '<h4> If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged </h4>'
            }; 

            smtpTransporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, req){
                console.log('mail sent');
                console.log ('success', 'An e-mail has been sent to ' + user.email + 'with further instructions to reset password.');
                done(err, 'done');
            });

        }
    ], function(err){
        if (err) return next(err);

    });
});
app.get ('/reset/:token', function(req, res){
    user.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: {$gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user, req){
        if (!user){
            console.log ('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');

        }
       // if(req.body.password === req.body.confirm) {
           // user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err, token) {
                user.password = req.body.password;
                user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
                user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;
                console.log('password' + user.password + 'and the user is' + user)

              //  )

            })
       // } else {
            //console.log ("error", "Passwords do not match.");

       // }
// });
},
function(user, done) {
   const smtpTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
       service: 'Gmail',
       auth: {
           user: 'preciousegunjobi1@gmail.com',
           pass: 'Presidoe2011!'
       }
   });
   const mailOptions = {
       to: user.email,
       from: 'preciousegunjobi1@gmail.com',
       subject: 'Your password has been changed',
       text: 'Hello, \n\n' +
        'This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + user.email + ' has just been changed.'
   };
   smtpTransporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, req) {
       console.log ('success', 'Success! Your password has been changed.');
       done(err);
   });
});

//end of forgot password logic
```

Comment: Hi Precious, welcome to stackoverflow! Any `specific` error you've? I don't think somebody here will run all your code to check what `exactly` doesn't work

Comment: Thanks @Alex. (sequelize) Warning: Model attributes (email) passed into finder method options of model userLogin, but the options.where object is empty. Did you forget to use options.where?
Executing (default): SELECT [email], [password], [hash], [phone], [first_name], [last_name], [address_first], [address_second], [country], [city], [state], [zipcode], [wallet_id], [languages], [gender], [resetPasswordExpires], [resetPasswordToken], [school_attended], [id], [user_type], [is_online] FROM [user_node] AS [userLogin] ORDER BY [userLogin].[id] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947876/cannot-read-property-findone-of-undefined-in-node-and-sequelize - seems to be similar

Comment: thanks a lot @Alex  . I have tried making changes using the content of the link you posted as a guide. I am not getting any error on my cmd when I run it, but my postman says "Could not get any response". Its still not doing the needful.

Comment: maybe `https://` instead of `http://`?

Comment: @Alex i do not get what you mean by that last comment.

Comment: what the protocol you're using in postman? https or http? And which one should be used?

Comment: @Alex i am still running on localhost